# Can We Access Facebook Api Using Postman client

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, postman

I want to access my full details using facebook api . I am using **postman client** for this and hit api as

```
  URL :  graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me
  METHOD : GET
  HEADER PARAMETER :
   AccessToken : djbjd
   AppID : dsdmds
   AppSecret :sdkkd
```

Now I get response :

STATUS : 400 Bad Request and Response

```
"error": {
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "AQt0krgrd2U"
}
```

}

Can anyone tell me how I can hit facebook api using postman client .

Comment: well, you need to use an active token. did you use an active token?

Comment: @luschn yes i am using active token . I thing there is some issue in header parameter or key please check it i have used correct key name or not

Comment: is it a user token or a page token?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You only need one GET parameter for this, the `access_token` parameter. It must be a valid User Token or Page Token.

You can also just try this in the browser directly: `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx`

Comment: Can you explain how to get a valid access token?

Comment: or the official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: I generate a token using the API explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 6):

I've been using Bearer Token to input the access token on Postman Client. The cool thing about it is you can add it to the folder and have every query inside the folder inherit it from the parent.

This lets me focus on the call and use each folder as an environment for calls related to the same object Page, App, Messenger and other tests